# adobe illustrator export from eps

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm newbie with adobe illustrator and I have eps file which contains 3 banner and I want to export each of them separately but it export them with 2 issues

1. images are not in center
2. images have extra parts around (padding's!)

## Screenshot

[image: one]

[image: two]

## Question

How can I export my images properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

I've made new document included 3 artboards and copied each one of my images in separate artboard then I export my artboards with checking `Use Artboard` option.

Now I can export my images as I wished. Hope it help others as well.